# CSS grid displaying incorrectly in Google Chrome browser

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid layout to have a 3 column layout. Even though I have mentioned the `list1` to span across 3 rows, the `list1` is only spanning one row.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #5a2916;
}

.item1 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.item2 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">One</div>
  <div class="item2">Two</div>
  <div class="item3">Three</div>
  <div class="item4">Four</div>
  <div class="item5">Five</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: item1 is as wide as 3 columns in google chrome + google canary browsers ....

Comment: Don't you have to specific a row height for this to work?

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you please eloborate. I am not getting your answer.

Comment: Rows don't have a height automatically. Telling an element to span multiple rows of zero height isn't going to get you far.

Comment: `.item1` is spaning 3 rows in Chrome.... please provide more info

Comment: @DomenikReitzner  No. If you run the code snippet, you can see that the row 'one' is spanning only one row.

Comment: Sorry my mistake: I assumed since you only defined grid-template column (and not grid-template-row) that you meant for it to span 3 columns which it does. As @Lazarnikolic mentioned you have to define the rows...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `grid-auto-rows` property to your grid. Like:

```
 grid-auto-rows: 50px;
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #5a2916;
  
}

.item1 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.item2 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">One</div>
  <div class="item2">Two</div>
  <div class="item3">Three</div>
  <div class="item4">Four</div>
  <div class="item5">Five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am understanding these now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you ought to add in wrapper class definition how many rows you want your wrapper to span.
When I added this       `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);` item1 went from one to three rows.